# How to apply a function (some processing steps) only on a specific part of an image in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, partial, apply, segment

I have an image X(m by n) and it is sent to a segmentation process. The new image, Y(m by n), contains 9 segments. However, the segments are some random shapes (I mean, they are not square or rectangular).

Now I need to apply other algorithms separately on each segment. Noting that the segments are non-square or non-rectangular, I cannot use techniques such as BlockProc.

How can I read each segment separately and then apply a specific process only on that segment? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: While 'segmentation' is appropriate, the term 'segment' in this context is confusing (it could describe lines). Consider editing your question and replace with 'objects'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
Props=regionprops(YourBinaryImage, 'Image');
```

Then retrieve a cell of the individual objects with `Props.Image` 
Then apply the function of your choice to each object using `cellfun`, for example.

Hope it helps.